# Rvalue constructor not being called?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, move-constructor

I have this struct

```
struct A {
    A()             { cout << "Default\n"; }
    A(const A& a)   { cout << "Const lvalue\n"; }
    A(const A&& a)  { cout << "Const rvalue\n"; }
    A(A& a)         { cout << "Lvalue\n"; }
    A(A&& a)        { cout << "Rvalue\n"; }
};
```

which I'm using to understand rvalues/lvalues.

When doing

```
A a1;
A a2{ a1 };

const A a3;
A a4{ a3 };
```

It correctly outputs

```
> Default
> lvalue
> Default
> Const lvalue
```

The problem is that when I do something like

```
A a{ A() };
```

The output is *Default*. But isn't `A()` an rvalue there? Shouldn't `A::A(A&&)` or `A::A(const A&&)` have to be called? what is happening here?

Comment: Allow me to direct you to [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem, but why in the example I gave neither any constructor was called?

Comment: Copy constructor is not certain to be called. In this case probably compiler created `A()` directly in place of `a` without copying.

Comment: copy elision occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not seeing `Rvalue` printed because the compiler is [eliding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) the move. This is allowed *even if the constructor has side effects*.

If you pass `-fno-elide-constructors` to GCC or Clang then you will see the output:

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -O2 -pedantic -fno-elide-constructors main.cpp && ./a.out
Default
Rvalue

clang++ -std=c++14 -O2 -pedantic main.cpp && ./a.out
Default
```